# Clockwork won't run a job in the closest full hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jobs, clockwork

I'm using clockwork for running a job every full hour (**:00), like this:

```
every(1.hour, 'auto lock', :at => '**:00')
```

But if a add an item for the job, for example at 17:50, the job will run for this item only at 19:00 and not at 18:00 as expected.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it calculates `17:50` plus one hours is `18:50` then it will wait for the `**:00` and that will be `19:00`, but I never used the gem and I do not have enough info.. could you give us more info please ? thanks

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioBertoglio, what info do you need exactly? You can see more info about this gem here: https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork

Comment: Hello @bl0ck3d - I wasn't able to replicate this locally, and in fact it worked fine for me. The logic for when an event triggers is pretty clearly outlined here (https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork/blob/master/lib/clockwork/event.rb#L65). Do you by any chance have `skip_first_run` set to `true`? That would exhibit exactly this sort of behavior. If not, could you share your `clock.rb` file?